# Will I lose my Anarchy stacks when I respec?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've been building Gaige with the [smaller, lighter, faster](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Smaller,_Lighter,_Faster) skills, but now that I've found an [Infinity](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity), I'd like to respec so I can use it.  However, I don't want to lose all my anarchy stacks.  Will respeccing make me lose all my anarchy?

Comment: I'd guess yes. As there is no "respec" operation, but "reset skills", it will take away your stacks with Anarchy skill. Otherwise you could rack up some stacks and then respec totally into another tree...

Comment: Why don't you give that Infinity to another character?  The downsides of using it with an Anarchy based Mechromancer are far too high compared to not having to reload.

Comment: @MBraedley actually its not too bad, just a 24% reload hit but the fact that I can now just hold the trigger down and run at full speed makes it very appealing once the anarchy stacks are maxed out.

Comment: @spartacus: Actually, I forgot the biggest downside: You can't fire the Infinity if you have even one point in _Smaller, Lighter, Faster_.  This makes the rest of _Orderd Chaos_ unavailable.  No _Discord_, maxing out at 150 stacks, no _Blood Soaked Shields_, I'd argue you're loosing a lot just to have Anarchy.

Comment: @MBraedley yea, that's a good point :/  Oh well.  I wonder if I can balance out the smaller clip by find a relic that boosts clip size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because once you reset all of your skills, you won't even have the anarchy skill anymore.

Comment: damn, I guess i have to just suck it up and rebuild my anarchy if I want to use infinity